# Ruby, tiny_tds segmentation fault (build tree)

Tags: sql-server, ruby, tiny-tds

```
require 'tiny_tds'

def client 
  client = TinyTds::Client.new username: 'user', password: 'pass', host: '192.168.4.4'
  client.execute('use database').do
  client
end

def services(id)
  out = []
  client.execute('exec GetServiceByServiceGroup @ServiceGroup = %s' % id).each(:symbolize_keys => true) do |s|
    out << {:value => s[:ServiceName] + ' <i>(' + s[:ServiceID].to_s + ')</i>',
      :child => operational_services(s[:ServiceID])}
  end
  out
end

def operational_services(id)
  out = []
  client.execute('exec GetOperationalServiceByService @Service = %s' % id).each(:symbolize_keys => true) do |os|
    out << {:value => os[:OperationalServiceName] + ' <i>(' + os[:OperationalServiceID].to_s + ')<i>'}
  end
  out
end

out = []

client.execute('exec GetServiceGroupByDirection @Direction = 50').each(:symbolize_keys => true) do |service_group|
  out << {:value => service_group[:ServiceGroupName] + ' <i>(' + service_group[:ServiceGroupID].to_s + ')</i>',
    :child => services(service_group[:ServiceGroupID])}
end

out
```

i take error:

```
test.irb:28: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x0000000000000e
ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [x86_64-linux]
```

I want to build tree with tree level from database, but tiny_tds return me sg =( why?
i write function "client" to cleate other connection while current return values. Else tiny_tds say 'Attempt to initiate a new Adaptive Server operation with results pending (TinyTds::Error)'

where i'am wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but these working

```
def client 
  if @client.nil?
    @client = TinyTds::Client.new username: 'user', password: 'pass', host: '192.168.4.4'
    @client.execute('use database').do
    def @client.execute(sql)
      puts sql
      super(sql).each(:symbolize_keys => true)
    end
  end
  @client
end
```